# intent filter for "complete action using"

Tags: android, xamarin, android-manifest, intentfilter

I've try to implement this code so my app appear whenever the user try to send a message:

```
[IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionSendto, Intent.ActionSend },
Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryBrowsable, Intent.CategoryDefault },
DataSchemes = new String [] { "sms" , "smsto" } 
, DataMimeType = "text/plain")]
```

but when i build this project and open the AndroidManifest i've got this:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
    <data />
    <data />
  </intent-filter>
```

i need to know what to do in order for the last two data tags to be like this:

```
<data android:scheme="sms" />
<data android:scheme="smsto" />
```

or is there any possible way to change the AndroidManifest manual in Xamarin

Comment: you can just edit the manifest directly

Comment: No i can't when ever i rebulid the project anything i edit in there removed by Xamarin

Comment: Are you using VS or XS?

Comment: i've been told that the AndroidManifest  in properties just temp and the real one Xamarin generate it when you build the project and can be found in obj\Debug folder

Comment: @Jason im using VS

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/working_with_androidmanifest.xml/